# Improve readability of boolean parameter in PHP function

Tags: php

I have read articles (e.g. [here](http://www.pixelstech.net/article/1335076725-Do-NOT-use-boolean-variable-as-function-parameters) and [here](http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2011/08/hall-of-api-shame-boolean-trap.html)) that suggest it harms readability to use boolean variables in function parameters. This makes sense to me; it's hard to determine what "false" means when calling a function with myFunction(false). It would be better if the argument in the function call was more descriptive. Something to indicate *what* is being set true/false.

What is a good way to have a boolean or boolean-like parameter in a PHP function that is more descriptive than true/false?

Comment: Define some constants that have significance to that function. e.g. `define ('DISABLE_LOGGING', false); define ('ENABLE_LOGGING', true); myFunction(ENABLE_LOGGING);`

Comment: @MarkBaker: thanks, sounds like a good option.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming You have a method like this:

```
function fetchProducts($useCaching) { /* ... */ }
```

And you call it like this:

```
fetchProducts(true)
```

You could instead:

1) create two seperate methods:

```
fetchProducts()
fetchFreshProducts()
```

2) or call it like so:

```
fetchProducts($useCaching = true)
```

The second thing is useful also for other types of data. For example when you're calling a method, which accepts 2 integers as parameters. But don't do it if You aren't doing OOP paradigm. You do not want to pollute global scope with new variable names to gain some readability.

Comment: `fetchProducts($useCaching = true)` - that approach appeals to me because it is nicely readable, but I've read that it's a bad idea because the effect is that you define $useCaching as true in the global context. Is this a big deal? I'm pretty new to PHP.

Comment: Yeah, it is a big deal. This aproach works well only with object methods - when you are coding in OOP paradigm. Then You're polluting just the scope of a given method - which isn't a problem - and it pays off to gain readability this way.

Comment: With boolean type parameters You should probably just create two seperate methods. This is actually a tip by [Uncle Bob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Cecil_Martin), and searching for reference I even found a relevant [meme](http://memegenerator.net/instance/39447402) :D.

Comment: I can see the point about creating two separate methods/functions, but it seems like it would mean duplicating code. An article [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Coding_conventions/PHP) suggests "either use class constants, and make a generic flag parameter or make your function accept an array of named parameters". Will do some more studying.

Comment: This is not going to increase the memory consumption since you're creating a variable?

Comment: @HenriCavalcante Maybe, doesn't matter. Readability > microoptimization. If you care about those kind of things - don't choose PHP.